# Angularjs ng-repeat: how to target an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, cordova

I have a list of div elements, when the customer selected an element, the detail view appear.
After the back, i want to target my list on selected element.

```
<div id="patient{{patient.PId}}" class="div-patient" ng-repeat="patient in patients">
   <p>{{patient.name}}</p>
</div>
```

I have tested many code to scroll on a selected patient:

```
$(window).scrollTop($("#patient"+$rootScope.selectedPatient).offset().top);
// or
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop:angular.element("#patient"+$rootScope.selectedPatient).prop( 'offsetTop' ) });
//or
$(window).scrollTop(angular.element("#patient"+$rootScope.selectedPatient).prop( 'offsetTop' ));
```

The css div-patient:

```
position: absolute;
height: 330px;
margin-bottom: 30px;
top: {{360*fixTopCell($index)}}px;
```

But

```
$("#patient"+$rootScope.selectedPatient).offset().top
```

and

```
angular.element("#patient"+$rootScope.selectedPatient).prop( 'offsetTop' )
```

Return 0 all the time.

It works when I use a *table* tag instead of a *div*.

I see that the function scrollTop is not available in Android 4.X.
Are there others solutions to target the element selected after a back on list?

Comment: How about this? $("#patient"+$rootScope.selectedPatient)[0].offsetTop

Comment: Besides your question, You are overusing jquery!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background?lq=1

Comment: @Ilan Frumer I use JQuery in directive.js. It's a problem?

Comment: First let me see your code. The way you use **selectors** is probably not "the angular way".

Comment: @IlanFrumer Sorry but this is not exactly my code. I can not publish the real source code of this appplication.

Comment: as @JeffAtwood says: `in a world of small and large businesses using .NET that really aren't interested in sharing their code with the world – probably because they know it would suck if they did, anyway.` -> [link](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2013/03/why-ruby.html)

Comment: @IlanFrumer I am agree with this but my boss didn't... and i like my job^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It works when i use a table tag INSTEAD of a div.

Make sure your id is not already used `#patient`. Maybe you try to call an id already used!